# combine solr 10 schemaless mode and _childDocuments_

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

when trying to add a json like this in a schemaless collection.

```
{
    "add": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "Solr adds block join support",
            "content_type": "parentDocument",
            "_childDocuments_": [
                {
                    "id": "2",
                    "comments": "SolrCloud supports it too!"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "Lucene and Solr 4.5 is out",
            "content_type": "parentDocument",
            "_childDocuments_": [
                {
                    "id": "4",
                    "comments": "Lots of new features"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Solr complains with:

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "status": 400,
    "QTime": 1
  },
  "error": {
    "msg": "ERROR: [doc=2] unknown field 'comments'",
    "code": 400
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: show your schema.xml, your solrconfig.xml

Comment: I'm using default solr 10 schemaless example. my schema.xml is generated by solr. I have only added _root_ field to support childs.

Comment: It looks like an issue was opened for this on the Solr issue  tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-7091